# Showing that the operator norm of a positive semidefinite square matrix with entries from $\mathbb C$ equals to the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

**Problem:** If $A$ is square positive semidefinite matrix with entries from $\Bbb C$ (so it's a transformation from $\mathbb C^n$ to $\mathbb C^n$ for some $n$, then
$$
||A||=\max \{\lambda: \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A\}.
$$

This is a question from Michael E. Taylor's "Linear Algebra" except I added the complex entry part, a book I find almost too abstract. I'm trying to prepare myself for the final exam.

**Definition of operator norm**: $||A||$ is the smallest quantity $K$ such that
$$
||A v|| \leq K||v||, \quad \forall v \in V.
$$

**My work:** Being positive semidefinite we have that $A$ is symmetric, and so there exists an orthonormal basis $\{\vec{v_1}, \ldots , \vec{v_n}\}$ of $\mathbb C^n$ consisting of eigenvectors corresponding to real positive eigenvalues ordered such that $\lambda_1\leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$.

If $x\in \mathbb C^n$, then $x = a_1\vec{v_1} + \cdots + a_n\vec{v_n}$ for some scalars $a_i$. Then
$$
\langle A\vec{x},\vec{x} \rangle = \left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \lambda_i v_i, \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j\right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2 \lambda_i  \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2 \lambda_n = \lambda_n \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^2
$$

But where do I go from here?

Comment: You're trying to prove $\Vert A \Vert = \lambda_n$.  Note that one inequality is demonstrated by $Av_n=\lambda_nv_n$, so you just need to prove $\forall v \in V~(\Vert Av \Vert \leq \lambda_n \Vert v \Vert)$.  And I think that $A$ is self-adjoint rather than symmetric.

Comment: You can use the inequality $$0\le A\le \lambda_nI_n$$ and the property $0\le A\le B$ implies $\|A\|\le \|B\|.$